# Nginx returns default html for some users

Tags: server, python, proxy, nginx

I am newbie in system administration.
I have configured web-server with nginx as a proxy and gunicorn as a python server.
Web-site successfully works on domain http://victorywow.com.
But for some users it returns `Welcome to nginx!`.
I have two files in sites-available (`default`, `django`).
This is config for `django`:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name victorywow.com; #ip,^
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error-server.log;

    location /static/ {
        root /opt/django/wow/;
        expires 30d;
    }

    location /media/ {
        root /opt/django/wow/;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
        proxy_set_header Host $server_name;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
  }
```

My gunicorn is running on the 8000 port.
I don't understand why some users can use web-site and some users can't.
Much thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `server_name` only matches `victorywow.com`, but `www.victorywow.com` also resolves to the same server. Since `www.victorywow.com` isn't matched by this server block's `server_name`, it's matched by the default configuration, which shows the default nginx landing page.

Use something like:

```
server_name victorywow.com www.victorywow.com;
```

It's easy to go to `www.victorywow.com` instead of `victorywow.com`: type `foo` and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> and most browsers will take you to `www.foo.com`.

Comment: Thanks, it works for me!
Tell me please how to make redirect from www to without www

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7947030/nginx-no-www-to-www-and-www-to-no-www

Comment: check please my new question ( https://askubuntu.com/questions/935190/problem-with-nobodynogroup ), if you are able to help me. Thanks!